# how to run alertmanager at k8s branch cluster

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, opsgenie

i have no idea how to run alertmanager.yml to integrate with opsgenie.
what command should i use at terminal in order to make it run?
i tried `k create -f alertmanager.yml`  , but it shows:
`error: error validating "alertmanager.yml": error validating data: [apiVersion not set, kind not set]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false`

here is my alertmanager.yml, any suggestion?

```
global:
  resolve_timeout: 1m
  opsgenie_api_url: https://api.opsgenie.com/
  opsgenie_api_key: <my_opsgenie_key>
receivers:
  - opsgenie_configs:
    - teams: test_escalation
      priority: '{{ range .Alerts }}{{ if eq .Labels.severity "critical"}}P1{{else if eq .Labels.severity "warning"}}P2{{else if eq .Labels.severity "info"}}P3{{else}}P4{{end}}{{end}}'
    name: opsgenie
route:
  group_by: ['...']
  receiver: opsgenie
  repeat_interval: 5m
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `alertmanager.yml` file only contains the Alertmanager configuration that should be mounted to alertmanager `Pod` using `ConfigMap` or `Secret` (it depends on how did you deploy alertmanager).

I assume you already have Alertmanager running and just want to modify its configuration.
( If you don't have Alertmanager deployed, you can easily install it with e.g. helm: [helm-alertmanager](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/alertmanager). )

---

I will describe how you can modify alertmanager configuration using an example.

First you need to find a `ConfigMap` where the Alertmanager configuration is located.

```
### kubectl describe pod <ALERTMANAGER POD NAME>

$ kubectl describe pod alertmanager-0
Name:         alertmanager-0
Namespace:    default
...
Containers:
  alertmanager:
    ...
    Mounts:
      /etc/alertmanager from config (rw)
...
Volumes:
  config:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      alertmanager
    Optional:  false
...
```

In the example above we can see that the configuration is in `ConfigMap` named `alertmanager`.

You can edit this `Configmap`:

```
### kubectl edit cm <CONFIGMAP NAME>

$ kubectl edit cm alertmanager
```

or you can replace it using your `alertmanager.yml` file:

```
### kubectl delete cm <CONFIGMAP NAME> && kubectl create cm <CONFIGMAP NAME> --from-file alertmanager.yml

$ kubectl delete cm alertmanager && kubectl create cm alertmanager --from-file alertmanager.yml
```

Additionally, I don't know which version of Alertmanager you are using, but is seems that from `v0.16.1` we can use `responders` field instead of `teams`. You can find more information [here](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/issues/1818).